# Uniqueness of the fundamental solution of a 2nd order linear parabolic PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm reading *Avner Friedman, Partial Differential Equations of Parabolic Type*. Let
\begin{eqnarray}
L:=a_{ij}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}+b_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}+c-\frac{\partial}{\partial t}
\end{eqnarray}
be a uniformly parabolic differential operator. 
Is the fundamental solution of equation $Lu=0$ unique under the following condition?

Let $D$ be a domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$,  $T_0<T_1, 0<\alpha<1$. $\Omega:=\bar{D}\times[T_0,T_1]$. $a_{ij}, b_i, c:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ are bounded and $\exists A>0$ s.t. $\forall x,y\in D, t,s\in[T_0,T_1]$
\begin{eqnarray}
|a_{ij}(y,s)-a_{ij}(x,t)|\leq A\left(|y-x|+\sqrt{|s-t|}\right)^\alpha \\
|b_i(y,t)-b_i(x,t)|\leq A|y-x|^\alpha \\
|c(y,t)-c(x,t)|\leq A|y-x|^\alpha
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

If $LF=\delta$ and  $Lu=0\,,$ then $L(F+u)=\delta\,,$ and it would seem that $L$ has nonzero kernel. Are there conditions on $F$?